# Get current selection info from Froala editor

Tags: javascript, events, wysiwyg, froala

I am using [Froala](https://froala.com/) WYSIWYG editor in my project. I would like to create my own font-family select component which will display the current font-family. So I need to listen to changes of an editor's selection, each time get current font-family and update my custom component.

```
import "froala-editor/js/plugins/font_family.min.js";
import Froala from "froala-editor";

const editor = new Froala("#container", {
    events: {
        onSelectionChange: function() { // I need something like this.
            console.log(this.selection.get().fontFamily); // Eg. "Arial" or "Verdana". 
        }
    }
});
```

I only found `fontFamilySelection` option in the docs, however, it will show the current font family in a native editor's component. One way is to read the current font family from the native component, but it's not a very clean solution.

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: which framework are you using ?
React, Angular, Vue or are you implementing using plain vanilla js ?

Comment: @PeterHassaballah I am using React.

Answer (score 1):

Try these three additional event hooks

**input** - on user input

**click** - after clicking somewhere in the editor, perhaps into a different tag and font

**commands.after** - after any menu command, like the native font picker

These hooks allow you to query the font-family style on the current tag.

```
const editor = new Froala("#container", {
    events: {
        onSelectionChange: function() { // I need something like this.
            console.log(this.selection.get().fontFamily); // Eg. "Arial" or "Verdana". 
        },
        'input': function (inputEvent) {
            // after a user input
            console.log(this.selection.element().style.fontFamily);
        },'click': function (clickEvent) {
            // after a user click
            console.log(this.selection.element().style.fontFamily);
        },
        'commands.after': function (cmd, param1, param2) {
            // after a command, e.g. the user used the inbuilt font chooser
            console.log(this.selection.element().style.fontFamily);
        }
    }
});
```

Others might be useful too, from the list at https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events/